# How does iCloud music determine which songs to sync to iPhone?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

Let's say I have the following in iTunes

- A 100GB library
- iCloud Music enabled
- Less than 10,000 tracks

And:

- a 16GB iPhone
- iCloud Music enabled

Since iCloud Music is now enabled, I can no longer select which songs are synced to the phone:

[image]

1. How does iCloud Music determine which songs from the 100GB library to sync to the phone?
2. Is there a way to control which songs sync to the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Apple Music iCloud Music Library does is the following:

1. It will check all the tracks you have stored in iTunes and
2. See if they are available in the Apple Music catalog. If not, Apple Music will
3. Upload them to the cloud.
4. All these songs will be available from the Music app on iOS. If you play them, you will stream them from the cloud. If you would like to save songs for offline listening, tap the triple dots next to a song, and tap: Make available offline.

Because it works this way now, it is no longer necessary to sync via iTunes

Comment: It appears that most of the tracks downloaded aren't copies from the Apple Music catalog - I've got mostly ALAC copies of music and on the phone, it shows that they're ALAC as well.

Comment: @remus That doesn't change step 4 :). You should be able to select the songs from your iCloud Music Library you want stored on your phone, while all of them will be available for streaming.